# Can I create a chroot environment with /proc without administrator priviliges?

Tags: linux, sandbox, sudo, chroot

I am trying to make a chroot'ed, sandboxed build-environement, which creates itself from a Git checkout before proceeding with building the application. One of the requirements is that the developers doing the git checkout and invoking the build should not need admin privileges on the host machine.

unshare -r chroot

works fine - except there is no /proc which again means a lot of standeard stuff wont work.
Various methods to create /proc I have found with mount require sudo rights.

Docker does this but the developers have to be in the "docker" group which effectively gives them uncontrolled root access - then rather give them sudo rights.

I have found the "proot" which does some kind of emulation to do this. This, however, has some performance penalties.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: jww, you have not read the topic correctly: I am trying to make build-environment. That is highly to do with software development.

Answer (score 0):

You also need a mount namespace which will give you the ability to perform recursive bind mounts (and plain bind mount where there are no child mounts). `pivot_root` and the ability to mount tmpfs, so use `unshare -rm`.

With a pid namesapce you can also mount fresh instances of procfs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using bubblewrap (bwrap). For a few things using ttys, I had to let it run with pseudo uid 0 to work.

If I should do it now I would use podman I think.